# Are there any ADME predictions tools available for Python/RDKit?

Tags: cheminformatics, medicinal-chemistry

Is there any Pythonic way (a.k.a: a module, an rdkit package, etc) or an API I can use for ADME predictions? I need to prioritize some compounds for purchase/synthesis and some sort of ADME scoring might help me rule out most of them.

I am aware of tools like [SwissADME](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep42717) but given the amount of compounds I want to test, it isn't a viable option. Should I train my own model?

Comment: You mean, KNIME would be just fine, too? As this [2020JChemInfModel2660](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jcim.0c00019), for example?

Comment: This might be better suited for [matter modeling](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Buttonwood yeah, found that right after posting the question. It is my understanding that KNIME requires a license for batch jobs such as this one, though. Do yuo have any experience with it? Care to share? :)

Comment: @Leitouran The topic is too broad for ChemSE and really better suited for the sibling site (MatterModelling). Literature search (e.g. [this](https://doi.org/10.1186/s13321-018-0283-x)), the [RDKit UserGroupMeetings](https://www.rdkit.org/) (you equally find recordings on youtube) empirical application of rules (e.g., [Lilly rules](https://github.com/IanAWatson/Lilly-Medchem-Rules), or [DataWarrior](http://www.openmolecules.org/datawarrior/index.html) to crunch many relevant data at once) may be examples of tools and resources useful for you, so ChemSE can't give a hand-on tutorial.

Comment: I don't think is necessarily better suited for a modelling SE, since I'm not asking "how to make my own model". I'm not asking for a _tutorial_ on how to do ADME modeling. I know there's enough literature on _how_ to do it... I'd just rather not to, and I was asking if there was any tool readily available to so.